# Unable to switch Alibaba Cloud ECS instances from subscription to PAYG

Tags: alibaba-cloud-ecs

I have an ECS instance which is expiring on March 25(Today), I am trying to switch it from subscription mode to PAYG, so that I can start/stop whenever I need. But I am facing the below error

[image: ECS Switch error]

Can't I do that on the last day of the instance, or It has to be stopped before I perform this activity?

Answer (score 0):

ECS instance should be in **Running** or **Stopped** status.

Procedure

1. Log on to the ECS console.
2. In the left-side navigation pane, select Instances.
3. Select a region.
4. Select the relevant instance. In the Actions column, select More > Configuration Change > Switch to Pay-As-You-Go.
5. On the conversion page, read the notes and confirm you agree to the ECS Service Terms.
6. Click Confirm Conversion.

Source: https://www.alibabacloud.com/help/doc-detail/85517.htm